# Forward Planning for SQL Invoice Auto-increment

Tags: sql, innodb, auto-increment

I am developing a database system for my employer and part of this involves creating invoices. I've been thinking about the auto-increment ids on my tables, and to what extent I need to make allowances for growth of the business. I am utilising InnoDB because the system will be very comprehensive, and many records will get updated.

Simplified, here is what I have currently:

> **Office** *(An office/store of the business. Currently 2.)*
>   office_id (PK) INT, AI, UN
>
> **Invoice**
>   invoice_no (PK) INT, AI, UN
>   office_id (FK) *(Where the invoice originated from.)*
>
> **Products**
>   product_id (PK) INT, AI, UN
>
> **InvoiceLine** *(Ties products to an invoice to make the lines.)*
>   invoice_line_id (PK) INT, AI, UN
>   invoice_no (FK)
>   product_id (FK)
>   quantity

Firstly, while I'll probably never run out of invoice numbers, I wonder if there may be a better way to approach this, just incase the business does have an unanticipated expansion of offices and increase in sales. How would a large company with say 50+ stores tackle this? Would each store likely have its own set of invoice numbers starting from 1?

This is what I've considered...

**Option 1** - Should I make the invoice_no bigger than the standard 10 precision? Regardless of difficulty, could this be changed after deployment if we saw the current limit would be insufficient, or is this impossible/highly problematic?

**Option 2** - Pardon my ignorance but is it possible/wise to have a database made up of tables with different engine types? It is my understanding that with MyISAM, the invoice table could have a composite key of office_id and invoice_no, where the auto-incrementing number would increase separately for each office. Is this true and viable?

**Option 3** - Could I have new tables created upon the insert of new office? Create table InvoiceX & InvoiceXLine, where X is the office_id?

Is there a better, simpler method that Im just not thinking of?

Secondly, if the business expands and we were averaging 30+ lines per invoice, it is conceivable that the invoice_line_ids would run out in the long term. So I probably need a similar solution for this, except Option 3 above (creating an InvoiceLineX table for every invoice_no) would be completely impractical in this case.

Could I simply make the primary key for the InvoiceLine table a composite of invoice_no and product_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of a business question.  Until you know how they intend to send invoices, why would you guess?  That said, if I had to keep and eye on the future I'd keep a few separate IDs.

- A master, magic number that is just the sequential unique ID that's as big as you need (maybe an INT, maybe bigger depending on your business size),
- an "invoice originator" column being the store (or whatever) that generated it,
- another column for "invoice processing entity ID" being the store/accounts office that issued/needs to deal with it throughout its lifecycle.

That gives you more flex if you have, say the larger of a store in a state processing all invoices in that state.  Of course this is guesswork!

The point of all this is that you've collected a lot of data that will likely be useful in its own right and then your actual invoice number will be some combination of those things.

Use your imagination (or business analyst) about what else you might want to keep & use.

Can't help you with the DB types.

Do **not** have one table per location/invoice line.  That would suck big time.

A side note - you will always get gaps in your IDs.  They are unavoidable so try not to get distracted with that and insist on gap-free.  You can't get that with any level of performance and you probably don't even need it.

If you think you might need it gap-free or broken down by location, put in a batch job that allocates an office/store/whatever specific number at the end of each day.  That way you can allocate some nice numbers as you see fit, using the basic sequence from the underlying IDs.

I think the short answer is go with more or less what you have unless it proves to be wrong.  All your suggestions are do to with problems you either don't know the answer to or won't happen.